Do we need a too-easy or too-basic tag?
We have three questions on meta specifically related to the minimum required complexity of a questions.

What's "Too basic" or "General reference" for this site? Uses scope
How can we can encourage questions to show proof of initial research? Uses too-easy
To what extent should we allow questions asking for research about a general subject? Uses scope

I propose killing the usage of too-easy, too-basic, too-simple and simply bundling all of them under scope.

Yes, a scope tag makes a lot more sense.
I retagged the only question in too-easy and the tag will disappear on its own.

The majority usage of scope at this point in time is to indicate which topics should be allowed on this main site, in line with its description:

The scope of the main site: what questions are on-topic and what is
  off-topic

In line with this description I just removed the scope tag from three questions which talk about question scope instead. I do not feel this would make a question on-topic or off-topic.

What to do with otherwise good questions that seem a bit too broad?
What is the optimal scope for a question?
Is splitting a question in two an appropriate action on this site?

To come back to 'question expertise', which could also be considered scope, a recent review of Meta shows this is a major topic in its own right.
It would be worthwhile reconsidering my earlier proposal of bunching them all together in one tag. The scope tag could still remain, but we could create more specific topics and expertise tags perhaps?
